# Adding HTML li text to a new li list using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `ul > li` list , for each selected `li` it gets an class = `ms-selected` on `li` click.

Lets say i clicked on "help" and "please" from the list down here (the class: ''ms-selected'' is added):

```
 <ul id="cultsSelect">
   <li class="ms-selected">help</li>
   <li>me</li>
   <li class="ms-selected">please</li>
 </ul>
```

Now i want to use JavaScript to add this selected value to a new list.

```
 <ul id="newList">
   <li></li>
   <li></li>
 </ul>
```

**Expected Output:**

```
 <ul id="newList">
   <li>help</li>
   <li>please</li>
 </ul>
```

I did give it a go at least just longing the values to the console but because my not working solution was based on a click event for the ul it made duplicates on each click event.

**JS** - this is my latest try which duplicates the values because on each click event the class "ms-selected" is already added to the previous value and then gets added again.

```
$(function(){
var selection = [];
var count;

$(document).on('click',"#cultsSelect", function() {
var cults = document.getElementsByClassName("ms-selected"); 

for(count = 0; count < cults.length; count++){

      if(cults.length > count){     
          selection[count] = cults[count].innerText;   
        }
    console.log(selection[count]);
}

})
});
```

This only logs to console, but i figured for now if i could get this working adding to 'li' would not be hard. I would still appreciate a final answer and not just a fix for the console.log.Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To achieve this you can simply append the clicked `li` in `#cultsSelect` to the `#newList`, something like this:

```js
$('#cultsSelect li').click(function() {
  $(this).appendTo('#newList');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="cultsSelect">
  <li>help</li>
  <li>me</li>
  <li>please</li>
</ul>

New:<br />
<ul id="newList"></ul>
```

If you want to retain the original list item too, add a `clone()` call before appending:

```js
$('#cultsSelect li').click(function() {
  $(this).clone().appendTo('#newList');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="cultsSelect">
  <li>help</li>
  <li>me</li>
  <li>please</li>
</ul>

New:<br />
<ul id="newList"></ul>
```

Comment: The correct way to appreciate an answer is to mark it as accepted (or upvote it if you did not post the question) if it answers the question. Comments are usually reserved for clarifications/discussions on the answer which add value for future visitors (and not for comments like 'Thanks' 'Me too')

Comment: @Ylama For your reference:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment


Look under *When should I comment?*

Comment: @Ylama no problem, glad to help

Answer (score 0):

Pure js approach ; Please see if this helps

```
   var cults = document.getElementsByClassName("ms-selected"); 

   for(i=o;i<cults.length;i++) {
    var node = document.createElement('li');
     node.appendChild(document.createTextNode(cults[i].innerHTML))       
     document.getElementById("newList").appendChild(node);   
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple way you can do

```js
$("#newList").html($("#cultsSelect").html())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="cultsSelect">
  <li>help</li>
  <li>me</li>
  <li>please</li>
</ul>

New:<br />
<ul id="newList"></ul>
```